# Hibernate - Remove child elements

Tags: java, hibernate

I am searching for simplest way to remove "child" objects from one-to-many set.

```
<set cascade="all-delete-orphan" name="publicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelations" table="publicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelation" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">

            <cache usage="read-write" />

            <key>
                <column name="workId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="khartn.my.site.mysite.portfolio.models.PublicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelation" />
        </set>
```

Is it possible to delete all child elements from hibernate set, when I am passing empty `HashSet` (`[]`) to the main class's method `setPublicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelations(Set<PublicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelation> publicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelations)` ?

Answer (score 0):

can you prefer to use annotation I think that is simple way to remove child object from one to may set.

Comment: I can't understand, what you mean... Can you explain with the code example?